# JTransforms FFT: Difference between even and odd-case

Tags: java, algorithm, fft

I perform a FFT on an array of arbitrary length.
The [API](http://wendykierp.github.io/JTransforms/apidocs/) can be cited as follows:

> **realForward**
>
> ```
> public void realForward(double[] a)
> ```
>
> Computes 1D forward DFT of real data leaving the result in `a`.
>   The physical layout of the output data is as follows:
>
> if `n` is even then
>
> ```
> a[2*k] = Re[k], 0<=k<n/2
> a[2*k+1] = Im[k], 0<k<n/2 
> a[1] = Re[n/2]
> ```
>
> if `n` is odd then
>
> ```
> a[2*k] = Re[k], 0<=k<(n+1)/2 
> a[2*k+1] = Im[k], 0<k<(n-1)/2
> a[1] = Im[(n-1)/2]
> ```

After reading several already answered questions on this, I am still unable to define the loop to get the magnitude value `m_k=sqrt(RE_k²+IM_k²)`.

What is at `index=1` in each case? (or do the authors actually mean `index=0`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the returned values in the `a` array are complex and returned in their natural frequency-domain order. There are however a few special cases which are:

- The 0Hz frequency component which is purely real (for even and odd `n`)
- The Nyquist frequency component which is also purely real for odd `n`.

The author then chose to put all the normal cases at index 2 onward and reserve a pair of values in `a[0]` and `a[1]` to handle those special cases. What goes in `a[0]` is the 0Hz frequency component. For `a[1]` it gets a little trickier. It's always part of the highest frequency component, but how to handle it varies if `n` is even or odd. For even `n` then the last frequency component is purely real and can thus be stored directly in `a[1]`. For odd `n` the last frequency component is not purely real so we still need a pair of array elements to store the result. In this case since the pairs started at index 2, and the array has an odd size that last pair wouldn't fit, so the author use `a[1]` for the missing element.

Perhaps the easiest way to see this is through a few examples. So, here is an even-length `n=8` example:

```
Bin  Complex result Comments
===  ============== =============
0    (a[0],0)       Purely real
1    (a[2],a[3])
2    (a[4],a[5])
3    (a[6],a[7])
4    (a[1],0)       Purely real
5    (a[6],-a[7])   Symmetric with bin 3
6    (a[4],-a[5])   Symmetric with bin 2
7    (a[2],-a[3])   Symmetric with bin 1
```

And here is an odd-length `n=7` example:

```
Bin  Complex result Comments
===  ============== =============
0    (a[0],0)       Purely real
1    (a[2],a[3])
2    (a[4],a[5])
3    (a[6],a[1])
4    (a[6],-a[1])   Symmetric with bin 3
5    (a[4],-a[5])   Symmetric with bin 2
6    (a[2],-a[3])   Symmetric with bin 1
```

Finally the corresponding code computing the magnitudes:

```
double[] m = new double[n/2 + 1];

boolean isOdd = ((n % 2) == 1);
if (isOdd) {
  // odd case
  m[0] = abs(a[0]);
  for (int i = 1; i < (n-1)/2; i++) {
    m[i] = sqrt(a[2*i]*a[2*i] + a[2*i+1]*a[2*i+1]);
  }
  m[(n-1)/2] = sqrt(a[n-1]*a[n-1] + a[1]*a[1]);
} else {
  // even case
  m[0] = abs(a[0]);
  for (int i = 1; i < n/2; i++) {
    m[i] = sqrt(a[2*i]*a[2*i] + a[2*i+1]*a[2*i+1]);
  }
  m[n/2] = abs(a[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So the length of m is n/2+1? `abs(a[0])` means `|a[0]|`? I wonder that i obtain very high magnitude-values.. Much larger as from an FFT generated using the FFT from commons-Math library..

Comment: Your if-condition does not work. I relied on your comments.. But it is unclear.. could you please edit your answer such that it is clear?

Comment: That's right for the length (assuming the usual truncating division for odd `n`). As for how large the generated magnitudes are, what [normalization](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/math3/transform/DftNormalization.html) are you using with commons-Math?

Comment: Thank you for your edits.. and for the preceding explanation in your answer too.. I got it from there moments after your comment.. So it is helpful.. And with  `abs` you mean the absolute, (always positive) value? I am asking because the magnitude is also refereed to as absolute value some times.. (It wouldn't make sense at all, as we miss an RE/IM part there... But i have to be sure..)... Yes forget about the hight of the value, I forgot the normalization I've used..

Comment: Yes `abs(a[0])` is using the usual [`java.lang.Math.abs`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs(double)) which returns the absolute non-negative value.